# Does all packages included in CentOS Everything ISO get installed along the base system?

Tags: centos, system-installation

The Everything ISO for CentOS is significantly bigger than the regular DVD ISO because it contains a lot more packages. Question: are these extra packages all installed automatically when I install the OS, or would I need to issue additional commands afterwards to install them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The everything ISO contains all packages, but they are still arranged in the normal category lists.
So it does not install everything by default, you have to install specific packages/categories that you would like to have available.
It is mostly so you can install whatever you need on a disconnected computer or install the system before connecting to the internet.

You can customize the packages installed during the installation to add what you like.

Keep in mind that there are conflicting packages in distributions so it's not usually possible to install everything.